# Google Analytics API Multiple Queries - Second Function?

Tags: google-analytics

This is a rather newbie question, please bear with me...

I have successfully authorised my Google Analytics API account and am making the following call, which successfully prints the bounce rate.

I want to add more queries on for things such as pageviews and sessions, how do i do this?

It's the functions which are confusing me, do i need to create a new function for each query?

Thanks In Advance!
Tom

```
function getResults(&$analytics, $profileId) {
  // Calls the Core Reporting API and queries for the number of sessions
  // for the last seven days.
  return $analytics->data_ga->get(
      'ga:' . $profileId,
      'today',
      'today',
      'ga:bouncerate');
}

function printResults(&$results) {
  // Parses the response from the Core Reporting API and prints
  // the profile name and total sessions.
  if (count($results->getRows()) > 0) {

    // Get the profile name.
    $profileName = $results->getProfileInfo()->getProfileName();

    // Get the entry for the first entry in the first row.
    $rows = $results->getRows();
    $sessions = $rows[0][0];



    // Print the results.
    print "<p>First view (profile) found: $profileName</p>";
    print "<p>Total sessions: $sessions</p>";
  } else {
    print "<p>No results found.</p>";
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following part of your code is what actually makes the API request:

```
$analytics->data_ga->get(
    'ga:' . $profileId,
    'today',
    'today',
    'ga:bouncerate');
```

If you want to make additional queries, you'll have to call the `$analytics->data_ga->get()` method again. You don't need to write a new function for each query (if you don't want to), but you will need to invoke `$analytics->data_ga->get()` each time. How you choose to reuse that bit is up to you.